# PHP extract value form a variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on WordPress plugin, It have a variable called  **$item**, which holds some data of a post.

I use var_dump function to display it's data,

```
var_dump($item);
```

but i couldn't able to get a value of a single item.

I just need to get **item_id** and **item_order**

Can someone help me to get this values and assign to a another variable.
Thank You

Here is the dump

```
object(LP_Lesson)#11313 (5) { 
    ["id"]=> int(6915) 
    ["post"]=> object(WP_Post)#11357 (29) { 
    ["ID"]=> int(6915) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2015-06-05 04:29:56" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2015-06-05 04:29:56" ["post_content"]=> string(5971) "" ["post_title"]=> string(20) "Add and manage users" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(1) " " ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" 
             ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(66) "test" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(9) "lp_lesson" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" ["section_item_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
        ["section_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["item_id"]=> string(4) "6915" 
        ["item_order"]=> string(1) "3" 
        ["item_type"]=> string(9) "lp_lesson" } 
        ["content"]=> string(0) "" ["lesson_type"]=> NULL ["_item":protected]=> object(WP_Post)#11357 (29) { ["ID"]=> int(6915) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2015-06-05 04:29:56" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2015-06-05 04:29:56" ["post_content"]=> string(5971) "
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far, accessing the data that you need

Comment: Since its a PHP object isnt it just `$item->item_id` ?

Comment: did you try `$item->id` & `$item->post->item_order` ?

Comment: @Regolith I tried by 
echo $item->get_item_order();
echo $item-['tem_order']; but no results

Comment: @AliAwwad It seems working with your way ;)

Comment: @AliAwwad i appreciate if you can post this an answer, I can accept that, Thanks for the help

Comment: @SunethKalhara thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since it is an object, just echo

`$item->id` & `$item->post->item_order`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
$item_id = $item->item_id
```

and

```
$item->post->item_order; //as instructed by @AliAwwad
```

?
By the way, I see that the id, is the same with item_id, so for that for sure you can do:

```
$item_id = $item->id;
```

Is there some scope indication that I'm failing to see?

Comment: It's an object, so accessing it as an array is not going to work.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out! I've been going front and back to python the last couple of weeks and my syntax gets mixed up!